# Python - Read Columns With Numpy

Tags: python

I have a file with lets say with the following X,Y,Z columns

```
#file.csv
X,Y,Z
1,2,3
4,2,5
15,9,1
#
```

I am trying to use numpy to read column X and give me the average, standard deviation and other statistics.
I cant get numpy to read them as columns like I want.

```
import numpy as np
import math 
my_data = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=',', dtype=float, names=[x,y,z])
```

if I do something like `np.average(my_data)` it is averaging every row instead of every column.
How can I make it average X, Y and Z  and  then print them out in a file?

And X have long numbers like 2747477447437.959843848 and I don't want to round them. These are IDs and should not be changed at all! How can I achieve this?

Comment: If X contains IDs, do you want to average them too? Also, if you don't want them changed, why not treat X as a string instead? Would that be OK?

Comment: I belive those numbers are too big to fit into a `float` without rounding.  you might need to try `np.float128` if your hardware will support it...

Answer (score 0):

Choose `axis = 0` to calculate the average (or something else) of a column. If you don't really need the first column, specify the `usecols` argument while using `genfromtxt` to choose the cols you want read.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: from StringIO import StringIO

In [3]: f = StringIO("""X,Y,Z
   ...: 1,2,3
   ...: 4,2,5
   ...: 15,9,1""")

In [4]: arr = np.genfromtxt(f, delimiter=',', dtype=float, skip_header=1)

In [5]: arr
Out[5]: 
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.],
       [  4.,   2.,   5.],
       [ 15.,   9.,   1.]])

In [6]: np.average(arr, axis=0)
Out[6]: array([ 6.66666667,  4.33333333,  3.        ])
```

Comment: This is basically what I was trying -- Although OP needs to get rid of the `names = ...` stuff which I believe creates a record array instead.  I'm not sure if that's important or not...

Comment: @mgilson -- If he wants to have named columns (for some functionality?), it think it would be better to use `pandas.DataFrame`.

Comment: I think the OP will need to add something like `dtype=(object, float, float)` to avoid the X column being misinterpreted.   I think `np.average(arr["Z"])` would still work, even if `average` won't work on the whole array.

Comment: or `usecols=[1,2]` to simply drop the first column, if it's not be touched (or averaged).

Comment: @DSM -- if he only wants the average of `[1:]` cols he could just use the `usecols`  argument...[beated @isedev]

Comment: there's a problem with using `names`: instead of returning a 2D array, it returns a 1D array of tuples, which can't be averaged.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful! I still have a small problem...
This is what I have so far and I am able finally to do average and other statistics: